# XSLT 1.0 Extract values from nested XML

Tags: xml, xslt, nested

I'm trying to get specific XML from existing one. Could you help please?

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<row>
    <column name="testName">Test 1</column>
    <column name="Tests">
        <XmlDoc xmlns="Customers servers">
            <Tests>
                <Test>
                    <cuFirst>Hardware</cuFirst>
                    <cuLast>Server 1</cuLast>
                </Test>
                <Test>
                    <cuFirst>Hardware</cuFirst>
                    <cuLast>Server 2</cuLast>
                </Test>
            </Tests>
        </XmlDoc>
    </column>     
    <column name="Company">Some Company</column>
    <column name="Company address" />
    <column name="Company URL" />
    <column name="Company Alias">Company Alias</column>
</row>
```

Current XSLT (not working as expected); I did try different things, but nothing; I will continue trying, but if you have any idea how to help, please do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="no" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Tests>
      <xsl:for-each select="//column[@name='Tests']">
        <ci>
          <xsl:value-of select="//column[@name='Tests']/XmlDoc/Tests/Test//cuLast" disable-output-escaping="no" />
        </ci>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <Test>
        <xsl:value-of select="//column[@name='testName']" disable-output-escaping="no" />
      </Test>
    </Tests>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Output XML

```
<Tests>
    <Test>
        <cuLast>Test 1</cuLast>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <cuLast>Server 1</cuLast>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <cuLast>Server 2</cuLast>
    </Test>
</Tests>
```

Comment: Why do you have `<ci>` in your XSLT, but not in the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

First thing: the `XmlDoc` element and all its descendants live in a *namespace* of their own; you must declare this namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix when addressing these nodes.

Also, in XSLT it pays to be explicit: avoid the // designation if you know the exact path.

Try the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cs="Customers servers"
exclude-result-prefixes="cs">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Tests>
        <Test><xsl:value-of select="row/column[@name='testName']"/></Test>
        <xsl:for-each select="row/column[@name='Tests']/cs:XmlDoc/cs:Tests/cs:Test">
            <ci>
                <xsl:value-of select="cs:cuLast" />
            </ci>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Tests>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Tests>
   <Test>Test 1</Test>
   <ci>Server 1</ci>
   <ci>Server 2</ci>
</Tests>
```

Note also that `"Customers servers"` is not a valid URI and therefore not a good choice for a namespace. Not sure if you have any control over that, though.

Comment: Great, thanks. My post was kind of sloppy, but the answer is what I need it.